# Tengo una secuencia en ORACLE que me suma 1 a un consecutivo, como muestro el valor actual cuando abra la APP

Tags: c#, oracle

Necesito mostrar donde va la cuenta para que al imprimir se muestre y con este codigo sumo 1 al consecutivo

```
// contar 1 al consecutivo cuando imprima
        var oracleConnectionStringBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = _cnnString,
            UserID = _schema,
            Password = _pswSchema
        };

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
        OracleCommand oracommand = new OracleCommand("get_secuencia", con);
        oracommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //OracleDataReader lector;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            LNumDoc.Text = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "xxxxx");
        }
        con.Close();
```

como hago para mostrar el valor actual de la secuencia, ya intente CURRVAL pero no se puede usar sin NEXTVAL que hace que sume 1 a la secuencia

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tendría mostrar el valor actual de la secuencia al usuario? Si lo tiene, me atrevo a decir que lo más probable es que una secuencia no sea la solución al problema. Y si no lo tiene, ¿para qué mostrarlo?.

Comment: Es un consecutivo de una factura, cada vez que se genere una factura debe tener un numero consecutivo

Comment: Los consecutivos generalmente no garantizan el que no haya agujeros dentro de lo que finalmente queda en la base de datos. Un ejemplo sencillo de esto es que, digamos que el consecutivo va por 10, haces un insert y te devuelve el número 11, que quedaría en el campo _NumeroFactura_, luego, haces rollback.

Cuando vuelvas a _insertar_ otra factura, el motor te va a dar el número 12, no el 11, como se podría esperar en un sistema de facturación. Los consecutivos no son para resolver ese problema.

Comment: Entiendo, que me recomienda para llevar el numero de factura de fomar que sume 1 al consecutivo al entrar al metodo de imprimir y me muestre el actual cuando abra la APP?

Comment: Eso yo generalmente lo hago almacenando en una tabla el último valor, o el valor siguiente de la secuencia, acompañada de una clase para gestionar dicho valor, que es la que actúa dentro de la misma transacción y se encarga de establecer un bloqueo  en dicho registro, aumentar la secuencia y devolver el valor siguiente. Esta misma clase sería la encargada de devolverte el valor actual, para que puedas mostrarlo al usuario. La programación de esta clase es la que tiene la lógica para preservar la funcionalidad del consecutivo, cuyas especificaciones suelen variar entre sistemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las secuencias no son efectivas para el caso de un consecutivo en una factura lo mejor es usar un procedimiento almacenado con una table que guarde el consecutivo asi:

1. Crear la tabla para el consecutivo
2. luego un procedimeinto almacenado
3. luego hacer la consulta

Procedimiento:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE get_secuencia(consec OUT NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   UPDATE EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO SET CONSECUTIVO = CONSECUTIVO + 1;   
   SELECT CONSECUTIVO INTO consec FROM EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO;     
END;
```

Ejecucion del procedimiento

```
var oracleConnectionStringBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = _cnnString,
            UserID = _schema,
            Password = _pswSchema
        };

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oracleConnectionStringBuilder.ToString());
        OracleCommand oracommand = new OracleCommand("get_secuencia", con);
        oracommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        //OracleDataReader lector;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            oracommand.Parameters.Add("consec", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            oracommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            LNumDoc.Text = oracommand.Parameters["consec"].Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "xxxx");
        }
        con.Close();
```

Mostrar en un Label

```
con.Open();
            consulta2 = "SELECT CONSECUTIVO FROM EQUIVALENTES_CONSECUTIVO";
            comando = new OracleCommand(consulta2, con);
            lector = comando.ExecuteReader();
            if (lector.Read())
            {
                LNumDoc.Text = lector["CONSECUTIVO"].ToString();
            }
con.Close();
```